# Pausing thread after button click

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I have the following code - it creates a UIActivityIndicatorView and executes a log in function upon button click. I need the activity indicator to show for a while before the function will be called, so I do sleep(10), but the problem is that the button gets stuck in pressed state (background color changes from white to blue and freezes) and the activityindicatorview does not show. When I remove sleep(10) it works fine. How do I pause the thread AFTER the indicator gets created and the button goes back to normal state?

```
-(IBAction)performLogin{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *view = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 13, 10, 10)];
    [view startAnimating];
    [btnLogin addSubview:view];
    [sleep(10)];    
    if ([self validatePassword] == YES)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToMain" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        [ErrorHandler showMessage:@"Wrong password" :@"Authentication"];
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use - (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg function, hope it helps you..

Comment: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToMain" sender:self]; check this line self not pass in self

Answer (score 0):

Move your validation to separate method, and call it after delay:

```
-(IBAction)performLogin{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *view = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [view setFrame:CGRectMake(180, 13, 10, 10)];
    [view startAnimating];
    [btnLogin addSubview:view];
    [self performSelector:@selector(performPasswordValidation) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
}

- (void)performPasswordValidation
{
    if ([self validatePassword] == YES)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToMain" sender:self];
    }
    else
    {
        [ErrorHandler showMessage:@"Wrong password" :@"Authentication"];
    }
}
```

Comment: i did but the transition is still happening immediately. Even when I increase afterDelay to a big value like 1000000...